# How can I create this navigation timeline

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design

[image]

Please how can I create this timeline in react js,it has a specific name but I don't know it, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs the content from the database and then bases on the content to create the link.
It should simple ul and li elements with flex-row css.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called breadcrumb